# HDD suddenly became blank

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, data-recovery, ubuntu-14.04

I have both Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8.1 installed. And I have two hard drives. SSD (With both OS installed on it) and old-school HD (with only one 450Gb partition and 1Gb unallocated space before it) with all the music and video stuff (but some important docs as well).

Today after restarting Ubuntu and starting Win before the actual windows boot the message appeared that my HD is being checked on errors. Ok, so the check finished and Win booted normally. But now my HD is totally empty with only `$recylcle.bin` folder on it. At the same time it still says it's 90% full. So it looks like all my data is there. I just don't see it because of some problem.

So I ran MiniTool Check File System and it showed:

```
Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ... 291776 file records
processed. File verification completed. 4710 large file records
processed. 0 bad file records processed.

Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ... Deleted invalid filename
liboxideqtcore0:amd64.postrm (43612) in directory 44944. Deleted
invalid filename liboxideqtcore0:amd64.postrm (43612) in directory
60382. An unspecified error occurred (6672732e637878 78a).
```

Then I ran `chckdsk /r E:` and it showed just the same as MiniTool.

Then I ran MiniTool Surface Test and it showed:

```
Scan Surface complete. 3 errors found.
```

If i go to Hard disk properties in files explorer and choose Tools - Error checking - Check, then is says there are problems and suggests to fix them but can't do it and finishes with the link to admin log where it is all the same again:

```
Chkdsk was executed in read/write mode. 

Checking file system on E: Volume label is Stuff.

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...

291776 file records processed. File verification completed. 4710 large
file records processed.  0 bad file records processed.

Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...

Deleted invalid filename liboxideqtcore0:amd64.postrm (43612) in
directory 44944.

The NTFS file name attribute in file 0xaa5c is incorrect. 6c 00 69 00
62 00 6f 00 78 00 69 00 64 00 65 00 l.i.b.o.x.i.d.e. 71 00 74 00 63 00
6f 00 72 00 65 00 30 00 3a 00 q.t.c.o.r.e.0.:. 61 00 6d 00 64 00 36 00
34 00 2e 00 70 00 6f 00 a.m.d.6.4...p.o. 73 00 74 00 72 00 6d 00 ?? ??
?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? s.t.r.m.........

Deleted invalid filename liboxideqtcore0:amd64.postrm (43612) in
directory 60382. The NTFS file name attribute in file 0xaa5c is
incorrect. 6c 00 69 00 62 00 6f 00 78 00 69 00 64 00 65 00
l.i.b.o.x.i.d.e. 71 00 74 00 63 00 6f 00 72 00 65 00 30 00 3a 00
q.t.c.o.r.e.0.:. 61 00 6d 00 64 00 36 00 34 00 2e 00 70 00 6f 00
a.m.d.6.4...p.o. 73 00 74 00 72 00 6d 00 ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ?? ??
s.t.r.m.........

An unspecified error occurred (6672732e637878 78a).
```

There is already no warranty on my laptop so I have to deal with it myself.

**What should I do?**
It doesn't mount in Ubuntu as well.
Please let me know if you need any additional information from my side.

---

UPD Added Crystal Disk Info screenshots:

[image: Crystal Disk Info screenshot1]
[image: Crystal Disk Info screenshot2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem myself.
There is a great tool Victoria. 
I have used it and got this great results.

Here is what i had before:

[notice 197 parameter and errors on the second screen](http://postimg.org/gallery/3e8e4pnlk/)

Then I restored all my data with R-Studio and after it did full HD Write with Victoria. 
And this is what I have now after it:

[All the problems has gone](http://postimg.org/gallery/260vjti8y/)

Many people recommended me to change my HD already )

What i'm still concerned with is Load/Unload Cycle Count of whopping 1500000

Comment: It's good you share your actual solution. The problem is this may be considered a software recommendation. As such it should follow [this outline](http://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/432690). I think you may skip the "give any personalized information to the OP" point.

Answer (score 1):

Your drive, although in a general good state, has 32 sectors that are unreadable and require relocation.

You should not have run checkdisk if another non-windows OS is present on the drive. Some of its files may have been damaged.

Please get HD Tune and perform a complete scan to determine if some of those sectors are bad.

Then, run a good disk repair utility (manufacturers data lifeguard xor seatools or disk regenerator) or the testdisk listed [here](http://www.gfi.com/blog/top-20-free-disk-tools-for-sysadmins/).

Comment: it's worth pointingnoit the author should consider a hdd replacement.  Eventually those reallocated sectors will grow.  A hdd only has a limited number of spare sectors.

Comment: Agreed, but the risk factor can be a lot more relevant if we knew if those sectors are permanently bad.

Comment: what do you mean by _You should not have run checkdisk if another non-windows OS is present on the drive. Some of its files may have been damaged._ My Ubuntu OS is on another drive. Both OS are actually on another drive, SSD drive. Do you mean I should never so checkdisk?

Comment: You should never run check disk if you have bad sectors at least not without a defrag before hand.  Check disk only verified the file system not the health of the hdd.  The file system will complain a file is on a bad sector, and react to it, as it being corrupt or unknown and just delete it

Comment: @SeyboGlaux Those liboxixxxx files mentioned in the logs are Linux files. That means you do mount the E: drive in Linux and use it from there. That is enough to cause issues. Ideally you should NEVER sleep or hibernate either OS and always do a full shutdown of the computer. Otherwise filesystem state will be inconsistent at some point. Either chkdsk in WIndows or fsck in Linux will make things worse if state is inconsistent.

Comment: @Tonny. That's true. I do mount this drive in Ubuntu. Why do you say it is enough to cause ussues? Isn't it normal thing to do? 
And I didn't understand about hibernate or sleep. What does is have to do with mounting?

Comment: @SeyboGlaux When a filesystem is mounted (for write) it will get updated. (Eg "last access time" will be updated even if you (or software running in the background) just looks at files.) When you hibernate there is no guarantee these actions are actually been written to disk leaving the filesystem in an undefined state. This is OK when you resume later, but if you switch to the other OS that OS isn't aware of these "pending" actions. Result: filesystem corruption. When you go back to the 1st OS those "pending" actions waiting aren't valid either, because 2nd OS meanwhile made changes too.

Comment: @Tonny, am I right, that this happens only in situations when I shut down one system unexpectedly so it hasn't wrote all the needed changes to disk and left system in an undefined state and then boot to another system? Would it be enough if i only be always sure before switching the OS that last OS finished it work correctly? 
P.s. I'm not sure there actually is hybernation in Ubuntu. I never saw anything like that there. And i don't use it in Windows.

Comment: @SeyboGlaux That would indeed prevent this problem.

Comment: @Tonny, thought you might wanna see my solution I just posted below.

Answer (score -1):

liboxideqtcore0:amd64.postrm( Linix file) means that you store here not only music and docs. Before restarting Windows did you update Ubuntu or change anything in settings?
If MiniTool Surface Test shows there are some errors here, it means bad sectors have appeared as sudden errors usually tell about it.
Or sometimes virus can create a hidden folder and move all the users’ files there, so you should set the option “show hidden files” in the settings of the file explorer, and check which data exists.

Comment: thanks for you reply, but I don't understand what do you mean by _liboxideqtcore0:amd64.postrm( Linix file) means that you store here not only music and docs._ Yes, there were some program files as well probably.

About you question. Yes, there was ubuntu update today. But it's almost every day ) And about hidden files: I do set this option to on always. And there is none files hidden. Actually Recycle.bin is hidden